# How to use eager loading to query as less data as possible?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Eloquent ORM and I want to set up a eager loading to query as less data as possible.

I have three tables `countries`, `states` and `cities`, and I want to get all the states and cities that there are in a certain country without additional information about that country.

My models:

Country

```
public function states () {
    return $this->hasMany(State::class);
}
```

State

```
public function country () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}

public function cities () {
    return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

City

```
public function state () {
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}
```

For example, getting all states and cities in USA. I would like to result a data like as follows.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'California',
        cities: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Los Angeles'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that using only Eloquent ORM helpers, without `where` or raw SQL?

Comment: Have you already defined the models and their relationships? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: I just edited. Check it!

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Comment: @jonas-staudenmeir
I was waiting for answers that use Eloquent Relations (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations`).
I don't think that the answers I got are satisfactory. Maybe I need to edit my question...

Comment: How do you mean that? Both answers use Eloquent relations.

Comment: Eloquent Relations, such as `belongsTo` and `hasMany`, allow me to create methods that can be defined and used with little logic and no repetition. Furthermore, they provide a powerful method chaining.

Unlike `with()`, that uses query logic and need to be re-written every time I want to use it.

Comment: That's not true, `with()` uses the Eloquent relations. Did you read the Laravel documentation? Did you actually try the answers?

Comment: Yes, I've studying Laravel Documentation. I was asking for a example that solve my problem using relational methods like `belongsTo()` and `hasMany()` instead of `with()`, as I told before. If you can't solve it like that, please be kind and don't make it exhausting.

Comment: Both answers use your `HasMany` relationships `states` and `cities`.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to put your solution, using `with()`, into a model method, like `states()` and `cities()`?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Like `states()` and `cities()`. Public methods that returns `Eloquent\Relations` and are written inside model's class.

Comment: You can use `return $this->hasMany(State::class)->with('cities');`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173721/discussion-between-zaclummys-and-jonas-staudenmeir).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the columns like this:

```
 Country::with('states:id,name,country_id', 'states.cities:id,name,state_id')->get(['id']);
```

You have to select the foreign key columns because they are required for matching the results.

You can also integrate it into the `states` relationship:

```
public function states () {
    return $this->hasMany(State::class)->select('id', 'name', 'country_id')
        ->with('cities:id,name,state_id');
}
```

This will automatically load `cities` when you access/load `states`.

Comment: Specifying the foreign key is unnecessary, atleast that's how it is explained on official Laravel docs -> ` When using this feature(eager loading specific columns), you should always include the id column in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.` lara docs->https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: It is necessary. In the documentation example, `id` is the foreign key. In this case, `states.id`, `country_id` and `state_id` are the required foreign keys.

Comment: in the documentation example `id` is the primary key of the author table not the foreign :/

Comment: The sentence in the documentation is badly worded, it only refers to `BelongsTo` relationships. In this case, we have two `HasMany` relationships. Try my answer without `country_id` or `state_id`, it won't work.

Comment: I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can you this:

```
$data = Country::with([
        'states' => function ($query) {
            $query->with([
                'cities'
            ]);
        }
    ])->get(['id']);
```

This is more readable and does not require raw query